# Can I completely disable next js ssr?

Tags: html, next.js, hosting, server-side-rendering, static-site-generation

So I want to learn how to disable NextJS ssr and host it on unsupported ssr hosting. I'm searching the internet to see if SSR can be fully disabled in NextJS by using NextPages, not NextApp, but I still don't know the truth because of a lack of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `getServerSideProps`. [Do use `getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering/static-site-generation).

Then run `npm build` and deploy the generated files.

The [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying) has further reading on the subject.

Answer (score -1):

No there is not. Also, if there was, it would defy the purpose of using Next.js at all, because that is not what it was designed for. If you need a client-side only application you are probably better off using something like [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev).